# prestashop where is subcategories query

Tags: prestashop

Hello I am using menu for mobile for prestashop 1.6 website. 
I want to shange displayed name of categories. 
I created name2 field for ps_category_lang table and filled with shorter category names. I want to show short names af mobile menu.

```
{foreach $subcategories as $subcategory}
    {if ($subcategory->id|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8') ne '45'}
        <li {if count($subcategory->getChildrenWs())}class="icon-arrow"{/if}>
            <a
                class="rm-level__item rm-category-{$subcategory->id|intval}"
                {if $subcategory->nright > $subcategory->nleft +1}data-load="{$subcategory->id|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}"{/if}
                href="{$subcategory->getLink()|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}"
            >{$subcategory->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'}</a>
        </li>
    {/if}
```

when I change $subcategory->name to $subcategory->name2 menu shows empty category names. 
https://addons.prestashop.com/en/mobile/17310-menu-for-mobile.html

where this subcategories created?

Answer (score 0):

You also have to modify (preferably and most recommended, override) the Category.php (in classes) class and add the field name2 in the Lang fields definition of the model.